# An identity involving the stationary measure of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

(Note this is a problem from Durrett, so I apologize if the notation is not standard)
Let $X_n$ be a Markov Chain, and $x$ a recurrent state. If we let $T= \inf \{n\ge 1: X_n=x\}$, then 
$$
\mu_x(y) := \mathbb{E}_x \left ( \sum_{n=0}^{T-1} 1_{\{X_n=y\}} \right)
$$
is a stationary measure. If we let $T_x$ and $T_y$ be the first time we hit/return to $x$ and $y$ respectively, define $w_{xy} = P_x(T_y <T_x)$. I would like to show $\mu_x(y) = w_{xy} / w_{yx}$.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to begin. I know that if the transition probability $p$ is both irreducible and recurrent, then the above measure is unique up to constant multiples, which I can then perhaps abuse as in other problems in this section, but unfortunately I'm not given that.

I'd greatly appreciate a hint on where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but I hope it is complete enough for you fill the gaps, ok?

So, $\mu_x(y)$ counts the number of visits to $y$ before we return to $x$. In order to $\mu_x(y)$ be non-zero, the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ must hit $y$ before $x$, this explains the factor $P_x(T_y < T_x^{+})$.

Now we hit $y$ for the first time, using the Strong Markov Property, we restart the process starting from $y$ and now we hit $y$ again with probability $P_y(T_x > T_y^{+})$. So, the number of returning to $y$ follows a Geometric distribution with parameter $P_y(T_x > T_y^{+})$.

A success here is returning to $y$ before $X$ hits $x$.

In case you have any problem understanding the argument, I can elaborate it.

Comment: Thank you, especially for formulating in terms of returns/hitting! I'm sure I can piece it together from here.